# Viewpoint Shading Mesh settings

Tags: mesh, 3d-view

ok so this is what my mesh viewpoint shading screen looks like, I was messing around trying stuff... but now I don't remember what I did.
can anyone help me set this mesh setting back to normal?
[image]

Comment: That looks like the result of a _Decimate Modifier_ set to _Planar_, any chance that's the case?

Comment: What do you mean by "trying stuff"? Please specify.

Comment: You are in wireframe shading, change it to any other one https://i.stack.imgur.com/UY35M.png